# Calculate the square root of Euler angles

Tags: rotations, quaternions, quantum-computation

I am trying to find a nice way to represent the square root of an arbitrary single qubit unitary to implement Lemma 6.1 from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9503016.pdf

Given the Euler angles: `Rz(a)Ry(b)Rz(c) = (Rz(a')Ry(b')Rz(c'))^2`

Is there a closed form expression that relates the angles `a'`, `b'`, `c'` to the angles `a`,`b`,`c`?

I have tried some simultaneous equations after I do the Euler angle exchange to have:

`Rz(a)Ry(b)Rz(c) = Rz(a') [Rz(A)Ry(B)Rz(C)] Rz(c')`, where `A`,`B`,`C` can be related to `a`,`b`,`c` via some nasty expressions found eg. on p4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09114.pdf.

But from there I cannot find a closed form expression for all of `a'`,`b'`,`c'`.

This seems like the sort of problem that must have been solved before - or at least it must be known whether a nice relation exists - but I cannot find work on it. Is it possible to go via quaternions or something?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell...

1) Convert $R_z(a)R_y(b)R_z(c)$ to axis-angle representation ([link](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToAngle/index.htm)).  You will then have a representation of $\{\theta, x, y, z\}$ where $\theta$ is the angle and $(x, y, z)$ is the axis.

2) Divide the angle by 2.  I.e. $\theta' = \theta/2$. You will now have $\{\theta', x, y, z\}$

3) Convert back to Euler angles ([link](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToEuler/index.htm))

And you are done.